# Will Samsung driver for notebooks get into the upstream kernel?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, kernel, ubuntu-netbook, samsung

I have a Samsung N150 Netbook and I installed Unity 11.04 to make some tests. But some functions do not work like backlight and vertical scroll on the touchpad.

There are drivers for samsung notbooks and I know that there is a PPA. But not for Natty. Will the drivers be avalible some day in the kernel by default? Will Canonical add these drivers in the kernel, if the Kernel developers wont?

I think this would be very useful because Unity is great for Netbooks and Samsung Netbooks are really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would get in contact directly with the developers through launchpad and advice them that you would like to provide testing feedback for Natty.

The more feedback they can get the better the drivers will function when Natty comes out for real at the end of April.

Its one of the reasons Open source works so well is because of the amount of communication between users and developers. Unlike the push button hope for something better reporting of other OS's.

[Get in contact with Voria here](https://launchpad.net/~voria)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that. And I will help. But I want to know if these drivers will land in the standard kernel

Comment: not likely but they may be included in the main Ubuntu/Debian repository (which would mean they could be installed during the installation of ubuntu) in my own situation I had to install a debian package from sourceforge to get my wifi running now the package is available in the repository.

Comment: @burli if someone is available to test and they work properly the Ubuntu kernel team can help push those drivers to the upstream kernel. Best thing to do is start helping and then contacting one of them to get the process started.

Answer (score 1):

There's a module called samsung-laptop for the kernel.
http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/samsung_laptop.html

Try using sudo modprobe samsung-laptop maybe? (I have some problems with it atm, but I already sent my problems to the author)

It should support N150, as it's in the source here: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git;a=blob;f=drivers/platform/x86/samsung-laptop.c;h=e0b390d45d8d83db295cc2012cd6e77f6279e843;hb=HEAD#l44